# Codeigniter & Phil Sturgeon's Template Library - Can I put view partials in a theme folder?

Tags: codeigniter, templates, themes, partial

I'm using [Phil Sturgeon's Template Library](http://philsturgeon.co.uk/demos/codeigniter-template/user_guide/) in my CI installation. When I try to put view partials' files in a theme folder, they do get called properly, but if I try to echo a $template variable in them, I get an error message saying that $template variable isn't defined. If I place those same view partials in the root views folder, $template is echoed properly.

How can I have view partials inside a theme and pass $template to them at the same time?

Comment: I should add that at the same time $template is nicely passed to the layout file which resides in
    /application/themes/themefolder/layouts/default.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was encountering the same problem. This looks like its a problem with some fancy hacks Phil had to use for compatibility with Modular Extensions.

If you're not using a parser, simply turn off parser_enabled in the template config file. Its the first option. Then it'll work.

If you're using a parser, you'll have to dig into the library. The problem is in the _load_view function, check lines 725-728. Something needs to be done here to get the variables to the parsed template.

Comment: Thanks for your help, Adrian. I think my problem was that the parser was enabled, as you suggested. I've gotten it right after all.